# What is taphonomic expansion?

Tags: paleontology, taphonomy

Fossils are bacteria colonies sometimes, a bone can expand with fluid. This is pretty common sense and I understand it.

But what is taphonomic expansion? Does it mean a fossil can be bigger than the original organism, just like if you let rice soak, it gets bigger?

Comment: do you have any source for where you heard taphonomic expansion? That would be a big help.